# Python recursive function does not return list object despite list not being empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I need to collect studies from a website than can only display 1000 studies at a time in xml. I have a case where there are more than 1000 studies and therefore I need to iterate until I have everything. In my case, I try to do this with a recursive function. I know that it is not the only way but I am so close that I would like to know what is going wrong here.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def collect_ct_ids(nct_ids=[], start=1):    
    url = f'https://www.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?&type=Intr&intr=%22NICOTINE+BITARTRATE%22%20OR%20%22PROSTEP%22%20OR%20%22NICOTROL%22%20OR%20%22NICOTINE+POLACRILEX%22%20OR%20%22NICORETTE%22%20OR%20%22NICODERM+CQ%22%20OR%20%22HABITROL%22%20OR%20%22NICOTINE%22&down_fmt=csv&down_flds=all?displayxml=true&start={start}&count=10000'
    print(url)

    # read xml
    response = requests.get(url)
    root = ET.fromstring(response.content)

    for child in root.iter('search_results'):
        n_studies = int(child.attrib['count'])

    # store studies
    nct_ids = nct_ids + [x.find('nct_id').text for x in root.findall('clinical_study')]

    print(n_studies, len(nct_ids))

    ## check that the default url allows to collect all the studies
    if n_studies == len(nct_ids):
        # return the studies
        print('if')
        print(nct_ids)
        return(nct_ids)   

    else:
        # reiterate until every study has been collected
        print('else')
        start += 1000
        return(nct_ids.append(collect_ct_ids(nct_ids, start)))
```

Basically, when the function should return a list with 1342 studies, it return None, despite the nct_ids object containing the 1342 studies.

Any help welcome.

**Edit2:**

The solution is to use .__add__ to add elements in the list and also no need to add to the list in the second return or it duplicates elements.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def collect_ct_ids(nct_ids=[], start=1):    
    url = f'https://www.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?&type=Intr&intr=%22NICOTINE+BITARTRATE%22%20OR%20%22PROSTEP%22%20OR%20%22NICOTROL%22%20OR%20%22NICOTINE+POLACRILEX%22%20OR%20%22NICORETTE%22%20OR%20%22NICODERM+CQ%22%20OR%20%22HABITROL%22%20OR%20%22NICOTINE%22&down_fmt=csv&down_flds=all?displayxml=true&start={start}&count=1000'
    print(url)

    # read xml
    response = requests.get(url)
    root = ET.fromstring(response.content)

    for child in root.iter('search_results'):
        n_studies = int(child.attrib['count'])

    # store studies
    nct_ids = nct_ids.__add__([x.find('nct_id').text for x in root.findall('clinical_study')])

    print(n_studies, len(nct_ids))

    ## check that the default url allows to collect all the studies
    if n_studies == len(nct_ids):
        # return the studies
        print('if')
        #print(nct_ids)
        return(nct_ids)   

    else:
        # reiterate until every study has been collected
        print('else')
        start += 1000
        return(nct_ids.__add__(collect_ct_ids(nct_ids, start)))
```

Comment: @blhsing: I don't get how my issue is related to the one suggested. In my case the object nct_ids is not empty as the print shows. But the return does not seem  to see it.

Comment: Please fix `return(nct_ids.append(collect_ct_ids(nct_ids, start)))` according to the answer in the linked question.

Comment: Saw that indeed. Thanks